# Compiler bug maybe? {$define isn't working as expected

Tags: delphi

I'm using 10.3.1 (4899). At the very top of the form in my project, I have a couple of lines that look like this:

```
{$ifdef AA}
  {$define BB}
{$endif]
{$define CC}
```

In my code I check the defines and act accordingly:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  {$ifdef AA}
  ShowMessage('AA');
  {$endif}
  {$ifdef BB}
  ShowMessage('BB');
  {$endif}
  {$ifdef CC}
  ShowMessage('CC');
  {$endif}
end;
```

Maybe this should be a competition: which message is displayed when I click the button? OK, give up? The answer is no message is displayed. Is the behaviour what's expected, or is it a bug?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507937/is-there-a-way-to-escape-a-closing-bracket-for-comments/17507938#17507938

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a bug. Your code is wrong. Instead of

```
{$ifdef AA}
  {$define BB}
{$endif]
{$define CC}
```

you should have

```
{$ifdef AA}
  {$define BB}
{$endif}
{$define CC}
```

Let's focus on the two lines of your code that are wrong:

```
{$endif]
{$define CC}
```

This is interpreted exactly the same way as a single `{$endif}`. So your code is equivalent to

```
{$ifdef AA}
  {$define BB}
{$endif}
```

Hence the observed behaviour.

You might wonder why

```
{$endif]
{$define CC}
```

is treated the same as

```
{$endif}
```

and the same as

```
{$endif]{$define CC}
```

and the same as

```
{$endif you can write anything that you like in here}
```

and the same as

```
{$endif you can even include left curly braces { }
```

Well, I've not seen that documented clearly anywhere, but it does appear to be by design. Once the parser has reached the end of the directive, it skips over everything else until it reaches a terminating `}` symbol.

For instance, the [documentation gives the following examples of compiler directives](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Delphi_compiler_directives#Examples):

```
{$B+}
{$R- Turn off range checking}
{$I TYPES.INC}
{$M 32768,40960}
{$DEFINE Debug}
{$IFDEF Debug}
{$ENDIF}
```

Notice the second of these examples:

```
{$R- Turn off range checking}
```

This is equivalent to `{$R-}`. The additional text is ignored and can be used to document the intent of the directive.

So this leads me to conclude that the behaviour you have observed is intentional, even though the parsing rules for directives do not appear to be documented explicitly.

Comment: So why did the code compile, if the curly braces are unmatched?

Comment: Because `{}` comments cannot be nested. So `{{}` is a complete and terminated comment.

Comment: I've seen this feature used for increased readability, e.g.
```{$ifdef ABC}
... conditional code
{$endif ABC}
```

Comment: Of course, I realised before asking this question, that I'd made a typo by using the `]` instead of a `}` but then i was intrigued as to why it compiled anyway. Thanks.

Comment: What actually comes as a real surprise is not that after `{$ENDIF` and up to the next `}`, anything goes. What comes as a surprise is that this can be multi-line. Most compiler directives cannot be used multi-line (I tried that a few months ago).